# how to display the current date data for the next 14 days

Tags: postgresql

i have data in database `tbl_product`
how to display the current date data for the next 14 days ?
with postgresql

```
id | tanggal     | item 
1    2022-06-14    Item a
2    2022-06-29    Item b
3    2022-03-01    Item c
```

```sql
select * from tbl_product where tanggal > current_date + (14 * interval '1' day)
```

but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [between](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-between/) operator to match a value against a range of values.

```
select * from tbl_product where tanggal between current_date and (current_date + '14 days'::interval)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
select * from tbl_product where tanggal > current_date + interval 14 day
```